# Step-wise finite element formulations: can this be done?

Tags: finite-element, ode, time-integration

Given the functional:
$$  
F[\mathbf{x}]=\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * D(\mathbf{x})]-\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * \mathbf{Ax}]-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}(0)\mathbf{x}(t)
$$

Where $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric, $\mathbf{x}(0)$ being the initial condition, $\mathbf{x}(t)$ is continuous, and:
$$
[\mathbf{f}^{\text{T}} * \mathbf{g}]=\int^{t}_0 \mathbf{f}^{\text{T}}(t-\tau)\mathbf{g}(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau
$$
and:
$$
D\left(\cdot\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(\cdot\right)
$$

We take the variation as:
$$
\delta F\left[\mathbf{x}\right]=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \varepsilon} F\left[\mathbf{x}+\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x}\right]\right|_{\varepsilon=0}
$$
Functional at the varied function is then:
$$
F\left[\mathbf{x}+\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x}\right]=\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}+\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * D(\mathbf{x}+\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x})]-\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}+\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * \mathbf{A}\left(\mathbf{x}+\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x}\right)]-\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)+\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\right)\left(\mathbf{x}(t)+\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x}(t)\right)
$$
The individual terms being:
$$
\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}+\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * \mathbf{A}\left(\mathbf{x}+\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x}\right)]=\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* D(\mathbf{x})]+\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* D(\delta\mathbf{x})]+\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* D(\mathbf{x})]+\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* D(\delta\mathbf{x})]
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}+\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * \mathbf{A}\left(\mathbf{x}+\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x}\right)]=\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}]+\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* \mathbf{A}\delta\mathbf{x}]+\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}]+\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * \mathbf{A}\delta\mathbf{x}]
$$
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)+\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\right)\left(\mathbf{x}(t)+\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x}(t))\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\mathbf{x}(t)-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\delta\mathbf{x}(t)-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon\delta\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\mathbf{x}(t)-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2\delta\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\delta\mathbf{x}(t)
$$
We can differentiate these with respect to $\varepsilon$ and then set it to zero, adding them up leads to:
$$
\delta F\left[\mathbf{x}\right]=\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* D(\delta\mathbf{x})]+\frac{1}{2}[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* D(\mathbf{x})]-\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* \mathbf{A}\delta\mathbf{x}]-\frac{1}{2}[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}]-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\delta\mathbf{x}(t)-\frac{1}{2}\delta\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\mathbf{x}(t)
$$
We also can say:
$$
\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* \mathbf{A}\delta\mathbf{x}]=\frac{1}{2}[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* \mathbf{A}^{\text{T}}\mathbf{x}]
$$
Since $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric, this just means that:
$$
\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* \mathbf{A}\delta\mathbf{x}]=\frac{1}{2}[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}]
$$
Substituting this back into the varied functional yields:
$$
\delta F\left[\mathbf{x}\right]=\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* D(\delta\mathbf{x})]+\frac{1}{2}[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* D(\mathbf{x})]-\frac{1}{2}[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}]-\frac{1}{2}[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}]-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\delta\mathbf{x}(t)-\frac{1}{2}\delta\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\mathbf{x}(t)
$$
Notice, now we have two similar terms which can be grouped, doing so yields:
$$
\delta F\left[\mathbf{x}\right]=\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* D(\delta\mathbf{x})]+\frac{1}{2}[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* D(\mathbf{x})]-[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}]-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\delta\mathbf{x}(t)-\frac{1}{2}\delta\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\mathbf{x}(t)
$$
We can lump this into the other term which a variation:
$$
\delta F\left[\mathbf{x}\right]=\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* D(\delta\mathbf{x})]+\frac{1}{2}[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* \left(D(\mathbf{x})-2\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\right)]-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\delta\mathbf{x}(t)-\frac{1}{2}\delta\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\mathbf{x}(t)
$$
Now, if we say that $\delta\mathbf{x}(0)=0$, we get:
$$
\delta F\left[\mathbf{x}\right]=\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* D(\delta\mathbf{x})]+\frac{1}{2}[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* \left(D(\mathbf{x})-2\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\right)]-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^\text{T}(0)\delta\mathbf{x}(t)
$$
This is the form I would use for discretizing, but we can show which system it is stationary with respect to. Taking integration by parts on the first term yields:
$$
\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* D(\delta\mathbf{x})]=\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}(0)\delta\mathbf{x}(t)-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}(t)\delta\mathbf{x}(0)+\frac{1}{2}[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* D(\mathbf{x})]
$$
Substituting this back in yields (with $\delta\mathbf{x}(0)=0$):
$$
\delta F\left[\mathbf{x}\right]=[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}* \left(D(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\right)]
$$
Which implies:
$$
D(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=0
$$
Or:
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{x}(t)}{dt}= \mathbf{Ax}(t)
$$

Again, the first variation of this functional (with no IBP) is:

$$  
\delta F[\mathbf{x}]=\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * D(\delta\mathbf{x})]+\frac{1}{2}[\delta\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * \left(D(\mathbf{x})-2\mathbf{Ax}\right)]-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}(0)\delta\mathbf{x}(t)
$$

I now discretize this over the interval $\left[0,\Delta\right]$, using the approximation:
$$
\mathbf{x}(t)=\mathbf{x}_0 N_0(t)+\mathbf{x}_1 N_1(t)
$$
$$
\delta\mathbf{x}(t)=\delta\mathbf{x}_0 N_0(t)+\delta\mathbf{x}_1 N_1(t)
$$
Where:
$$
N_0(t)=1-\frac{t}{\Delta}
$$
And
$$
N_1(t)=\frac{t}{\Delta}
$$

The result is:
$$
\delta F[\mathbf{x}] \approx \delta\mathbf{x}_1^{\text{T}}\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{I}-\frac{\Delta}{6}\mathbf{A}\right)\mathbf{x}_1-\frac{\Delta}{3}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}_0-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}(0)\right)
$$

Given that $\delta\mathbf{x}_1$ is some arbitrary discrete variation, we can say that it's coefficient must be zero:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{I}-\frac{\Delta}{6}\mathbf{A}\right)\mathbf{x}_1-\frac{\Delta}{3}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}_0-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}(0)=0
$$

My question is, is the following also true?:

$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{I}-\frac{\Delta}{6}\mathbf{A}\right)\mathbf{x}_{i+1}-\frac{\Delta}{3}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}_i-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}(0)=0
$$

Comment: I can provide an example if need be, I just don't want to bias the answer with any specific cases. Also, if anything is unclear, please let me know; I can explain or correct anything.

Comment: This isn't exactly clear. What is $\mathcal{L}$? What are $\boldsymbol{x}_0$, etc.? What are $N_0(t)$, etc.? I feel like you've left too much out.

Comment: @BillBarth: Sure. $\mathcal{L}$ is just the integrand, I didn't want to specify too much what it was, but the idea is that the variation of this integrand is stationary at the given system. $\mathbf{x}_0$ and $N_0(t)$ are associated coefficients and shape functions.

Comment: You should really write out a more concrete example.

Comment: You define your functional $I[x]$, yet $x$ doesn't even occur on the right-hand side. What are these objects you talk about? In which spaces do they live? You have to be more precise.

Comment: @eriatarka84: I've rewritten the question completely for a specific case, it should make what I'm asking much clearer.

Comment: @BillBarth: I've rewritten the question completely for a specific case, it should make what I'm asking much clearer.

Comment: @ChristianClason: That's actually not a nonlinearity, this really teaches me to be clearer! It's a derivative, I've made things clearer in the post. Also, since $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric, it will be positive definite as well, yes.

Comment: @ChristianClason: I've clarified my procedure, there was one sign issue, but it wasn't related to any mistakes you pointed out. Also, the prime was a transpose, I've clarified that as well. I'm not sure where you had trouble, but I made sure to explicitly show everything I did, you may have missed that I'm dealing with convolutions here, so the integration by parts is not quite the same. If you want me to show you how to do it, let me know. As you can see, due to the properties of IBP for convolutions, there is no terminal term.

Comment: @ChristianClason:  If you'd like, I can also show that the second variation is zero, which would address another of your points. Lastly, the term $\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}(0)\delta\mathbf{x}(t)$ is basically the dot product of the vector initial condition and the vector variation ($\delta\mathbf{x}(t)=\left[\delta x_1(t),\delta x_2(t)\right]$)

Comment: @ChristianClason: I forgot - if you'd like me to show how I did the bit with the shape functions, let me know.

Comment: @ChristianClason: By the way, this is an example of a convolutional formulation. There is a fair bit of literature on the topic, but Gurtin and Tonti are where I'd start if you're not familiar with them, they developed the formulation quite a bit. Tonti actually formulated this specific functional in his paper (although in indicial form).

Answer (score 2):

*(too many comments, so I'll continue here)*

I assume you're referring to equation (4.40) in http://www.dic.units.it/perspage/tonti/DEPOSITO/Initial.pdf. In this case the answer is yes, it is possible: Due to the specific integral formulation based on convolution, the first variation of (4.40) leads to the initial value problem
$$ x'(t) = Ax(t)$$
with $x(0)$ given. You can then discretize this equation with a standard Galerkin method; the one you are trying to get is equivalent to a Crank-Nicolson time stepping method.

In principle, you can also go the other way around as you are proposing: Discretize the functional, and then take discrete variations. Depending on the discretisation, you end up with different time stepping methods, but often there's one choice that leads to a standard time stepping method such as Crank-Nicolson. Whether that is possible in this case, I'm not sure -- the Crank-Nicolson method is equivalent to a Petrov-Galerkin method (i.e., trial and test functions come from different spaces; continuous piecewise linear and discontinuous piecewise constant, in this case), which means there can be no variational formulation (since the test functions come from variations of the trial functions, which means they have to live in the same space).

As regards your specific question: No, this is unlikely to be true, since the initial condition shouldn't appear there. To get the next time step, you need to explicitly compute variations with respect to $\delta x_2$ (and so forth).

(Note that in the definition of your functional, $t$ should really be $T$ (the end time), otherwise the functional makes no sense. (This means that $f^T*g$ is not really the convolution of $f$ and $g$ (which would be a function), but a related bilinear form (and hence a real number).) That means you need to be careful when taking variations not to mix up $t$ and $T$. Also, the $x(0)$ in your formulation is a *fixed* initial condition, better denoted by $x_0$. Since $x(0)=x_0$ is fixed, there can be no variation at $t=0$, i.e., $\delta x(0) = 0$.)

Comment: Thank you for naming the associated numerical methods. I was unfamiliar with them and looking them up to get a better understanding will help. I was truly confused about what to do with the $\mathbf{x}(0)$ in the formulation. Whether or not I should evaluate the discretization ($\mathbf{x}_0 N_0(t)+\mathbf{x}_1 N_1(t)$) at $t=0$ for the last constant term was unclear to me.

Comment: I'm currently working on the results of using the discretization $\mathbf{x}(t)=\mathbf{x}_i N_i(t)+\mathbf{x}_{i+1} N_{i+1}(t)$ for $\left[t_i,t_{i+1}\right]$ to see if what I posed was indeed true. Also, in the formulation I presented, $t$ was meant to be a terminal time, my mistake for not noting that! Once I figure it out, I'll come back here and amend what I have here/take care of the question.

Comment: Also, Tonti made a mistake in 4.40, it should be noted that there is a derivative missing there. And thank you for the help!